# Wouldn't it be useful to sort sites by title?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Now that the "all sites" button on the StackExchange page lists 65 sites (even though the side column still says only 63), wouldn't it be useful to let the "sort by" control also sort by site name (not just oldest, newest, traffic, etc)?

I happened to browse backwards to the page, knowing I wanted to click the Home Improvement site title, and it took me forever to scroll up and down trying to pick it out (probably blind from too much sugar).  It would have been a lot easier if I could have sorted by title, then scrolled right to the "H" sites.

Comment: Ohhh I like the little animation when they sort too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the "type to find sites" field at the top of the page there?

https://stackexchange.com/sites

Just type "hom" and you're practically there..

Comment: That is a workaround. Are you closing this ticket as WONTFIX or just providing a way to get around it? Sorting alphabetically would be extremely useful, just for browsing.

Comment: Because I never even noticed that control on the page.  In any case, I see that sorting by name is now available...